# Do bases on the 2 transistors in a differential amplifier have graded response for entire range of input voltages they use?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, differential

I come from a digital electronics point of view (really I'm a novice in general, but as a novice have mostly been interested in digital electronics), and there, transistors are supposed to act as binary switches, that are either on or off, 1 or 0, and optimized for that. Going from that world view to now looking at differential amplifier (mainly as part of operational amplifier but also as stand alone component), I am puzzled by that it looks like the diff amp should be able to have a linear, graded response to a wide range of voltages. That its 2 transistors must be able to increase or decrease current in proportion to the input voltage at base, in a way very very different from what I am used to with transistors.

This question is similar to a previous one, but much more specific because I noticed that helps with getting answers. So feel free to not label it "duplicate" because that wastes time and space. It is an improvement, v2.0...

Comment: Both transistors, and the op-amps they are made from are quite easy to produce with very high gains. However, they are not so easy to produce to accurate gains or stable gains. But with negative feedback, you can use the "infinite gain" to fight itself such that your overall gain gets reduced down to a fixed level that is determined by external components which are accurate and thus provide an accurate overall gain.

Comment: What do you mean by graded? BJT transistors are linear devices. For simple first order analysis, if the Vbe junction is forward biased, then Ic will be 100 times Ib. We live in an analog world, even ideal digital logic is implemented with non-ideal analog components.

Comment: @Justme You must understand what I mean unless I completely misunderstand how diff amp goes from input to output. If I input 1 volt and 2 volt, it cannot have maximally forward biased transistor at 1 volt because it would then interpret the inputs as equal, and not work. Same with 2 volts and 4 volts. A "diff amp" seems to support input ranges that are very different from digital logic transistors. I don't get this because I'm used to digital logic point of view. But to someone who gets it it must seem obvious and self-evident.

Comment: @Doge Yes, in analog circuits, such as the diff amp, transistors are used in the linear range of operation, so they are not fully off and not fully on as then the circuit would fail to work as intended.

Comment: @Justme OK interesting. The linear range must also be much wider than in digital transistors, right? In digital it is usually 0.7 V or something, right? Do you know roughly what ranges? (I understand this must differ a lot but just to have something to go by. )

Comment: @Doge the transistors themselves are rather irrelevant, as it is the circuit as a whole what it does. You can use same transistors in a linear amp and in a digital circuit that is either on or off, the circuit and how it works is different.

Comment: @Justme I might miss something with the circuit but to me it seems like input of 1 volt, or 2 volt, or 3 volt, or 4 volt, (and the other input at 0), must continuously increase voltage drop there around the output, so that it outputs the difference. And must do this by increasing conductance of the transistor in proportion to 1, 2, 3, 4. Digital computers that do this would not work would they? The base voltage is not that high there.

Comment: (It's possible I entirely misunderstand difference amplifier, my assumption is just that output must increase in proportion to input by conductance fo transistors being affected in proportion to input, and not some other effect. )

Comment: For a segue from digital logic to linear diff amps, take a look at old emitter-coupled logic **ECL**. They use diff amps as input stage, with emitter-followers for output. Very speedy, because hard logic "on/off" with transistors in saturation is avoided. Logic level biasing is carefully temperature compensated.

Answer (score 0):

Whether used in analogue amplifier circuits or digital switching circuits, transistors are transistors.

A 'differential amplifier' may mean an op-amp with a diff input and output, or a completely built amplifier, with active components, possibly op-amps, and feedback resistors to set the gain.

In the op-amp case, the input to output high gain will be more or less linear only over a few mV input voltage differential. Beyond that, the input will be overloaded. In normal operation, feedback from the output is added to reduce the overall gain, and to move the input common mode to wherever it needs to be to accommodate the input signal.

In the digital case, it's only over a few mV change of input voltage that the output actually changes state. However for reasons of noise margin, switching speed, and guaranteed compatibility with other gates, much larger swings are used.